# Docker pull ros returns no matching manifest

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, I am trying to pull ros using docker but I got the following error:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ros
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

I installed ROS Kinetic on Linux (Dont think it matters) and here are my info for Ubuntu:

```
4.15.0-45-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 18:03:19 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I suspect the reason for this is the fact that I am using a 32-bit laptop instead of 64-bit. Its there any way to pull the ros image on a 32-bit computer?

The image I was trying to pull is:

```
Sudo Docker pull ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323664/docker-pull-ros-returns-no-matching-manifest/) by [weiyuhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/41688/weiyuhe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-21**:
You don't show the image you're trying to pull, so your question is hard to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [docker success center: Error pulling image : no matching manifest](https://success.docker.com/article/error-pulling-image-no-matching-manifest) the problem would indeed be that you're trying to `pull` an image for an unsupported OS/arch combination.

> I suspect the reason for this is the fact that I am using a 32-bit laptop instead of 64-bit. Its there any way to pull the ros image on a 32-bit computer?

I'm not aware of official `i386` images. The tags on [hub.docker.com/ros](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros/) also seem to suggest only `amd64`, `arm64` and `arm` are supported. The *Supported Architectures* under *Quick Reference* also states that:

> - Supported architectures: (more info)
>
> `amd64`, `arm32v7`, `arm64v8`

It should be doable to build 32bit images yourself though: changing [this line](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/49d22242e02e9c541a9e85b657e1785617b6f470/ros/kinetic/ubuntu/xenial/ros-core/Dockerfile#L3) to read `i386/ubuntu:xenial` *should* work.

At least for Kinetic. There are no `i386` builds for Melodic any more (Lunar dropped this support: see [REP 3: Architectures](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#architectures)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1